# Triggering useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component and render it conditionally with different props.

```
      {activeNavItem === 'Concept Art' ? (
        <Gallary
          images={conceptArtImages}
          sectionRef={sectionRef}
        />
      ) : (
        <Gallary
          images={mattePaintingImages}
          sectionRef={sectionRef}
        />
      )}
```

This component has `useState(false)` and `useEffect` hooks. `useEffect` determines when screen position reaches the dom element and it triggers `useState` to `true`: `elementPosition < screenPosition`. Then my `state` triggers class on dom element: `state ? 'animationClass' : ''`.

```
const Gallary = ({ images, sectionRef }) => {
  const [isViewed, setIsViewed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const section = sectionRef.current;

    const onScroll = () => {
      const screenPosition = window.innerHeight / 2;
      const sectionPosition = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(screenPosition);

      if (sectionPosition < screenPosition) setIsViewed(true);
    };

    onScroll();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
  }, [sectionRef]);

  return (
    <ul className="section-gallary__list">
      {images.map((art, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          className={`section-gallary__item ${isViewed ? 'animation--view' : ''}`}>
          <img className="section-gallary__img" src={art} alt="concept art" />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Problem: it works on my first render. But when I toggle component with different props, my `state` iniatially is `true` and I haven't animation.

I notice that if I have two components(`ComponentA, ComponentB`) instead of one(`ComponentA`) it works fine.

Comment: Please include the code of the component. It's easier to read the code than reconstruct it from a description.

Comment: @OriDrori Update

Comment: @nukuutos you mean whe you change `activeNavItem` for second time it will not animate??

Comment: @adel Yes, you're right

Comment: I note that you should be using `setIsViewed(true)` instead of `setIsViewed(() => true)`

Comment: The `setIsViewed(() => true)` is fine, although not really needed in this case.

Comment: Your problem is that after something enters the view, `isViewed` becomes `true`, and nothing changes it back to `false`.

Comment: I'm not saying that change fixes your issue, but it is an improvement nevertheless...

Comment: When I render the component, firstly, `isViewed` takes `false` and then it goes to `useEffect` and takes `true` by condition or not?

Answer (score 0):

try setting `isViewed` to false when your component is not in view like this:

```
if (sectionPosition < screenPosition && !isViewed){
setIsViewed(true);
}
else{
if(isViewed) 
   setIsViewed(false);
}
```

and you can do it like this:

```
if (sectionPosition < screenPosition && !isViewed){
setIsViewed(state=>!state);
}
else{
if(isViewed) 
   setIsViewed(state=>!state);
}
```

plus no need to render same component multiple times, you can change props only:

```
  <Gallary
      images={activeNavItem === 'ConceptArt'?conceptArtImages:mattePaintingImages}
      sectionRef={sectionRef}
    />
```

Comment: It's not working. It cancels class by `screenPosition`, not by render component with different props.

Comment: well aren't trying to add animation class if your component is in view???

Comment: When it's once in view animation class must stay. when component is changed it must cancel animation class and adds it if `screenPosition` reaches `elementPosition`